# multiple generic type constraint in vb.net allows access to first type constraint members only

Tags: c#, vb.net, loops, type-constraints

I used 2 generic type constraint over class where I am able to get the all member of both type in C# code, but same implementation in vb.net allows to access member of first type constraint only.

Seems like I am using incorrect syntax in vb.net, but not sure.

**C# sample code**

```
public class MainCaller<T> where T :  ITest, ITest2
{
    public void MainCallerTest()
    {
        List<T> c = new List<T>();
        //Note:- here I am able to access the member of both the interfaces

        var x = c.FirstOrDefault(o => o.TestID == 1 && o.CommonID == 2);

    }
}

public interface ITest
{
    int TestID { get; set; }
}
public interface ITest2
{
    int CommonID { get; set; }
}

public class ClassTest : ITest2, ITest
{
    public int TestID { get; set ; }
    public int CommonID { get; set; }
}
```

**VB.net sample code**

```
Friend Class MainCaller(Of T As ITest, ITest2)
    Public Sub MainCallerTest()
        Dim c As List(Of T) = New List(Of T)()

        ''Note:- here I am able to access the member of only ITest interface
        ''       not the ITest2. (o.CommonID) is not accessible in below code

        Dim x = c.FirstOrDefault(Function(o) o.TestID = 1 Or o.CommonID = 2)

    End Sub
End Class

Interface ITest
    Property TestID As Integer
End Interface
Interface ITest2
    Property CommonID As Integer
End Interface

Public Class ClassTest
    Implements ITest2, ITest

    Public Property TestID As Integer Implements ITest.TestID
        Get
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CommonID As Integer Implements ITest2.CommonID
        Get
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: I always use this convertor... https://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: On the subject of code converters, I strongly recommend downloading and installing Instant VB and/or Instant C# from tangible Software Solutions. The free version has limitations on the amount of code you can convert but it is generally enough for most people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using just a comma you are indicating a second generic type parameter. Multiple constraints for a single parameter must be grouped with braces:

```vb
Friend Class MainCaller(Of T As {ITest, ITest2})
```

The VB code you have is equivalent to this C#:

```cs
public class MainCaller<T, ITest2> where T : ITest
```